# To split numeric part from alpha numeric

Tags: c#, regex

I have a AlphaNumeric value which may contain white space or under score in it.
  I want to split numeric from that and increment the value by one and need to join the numeric part back to Alpha part.

For example the Alpha Numeric may be : 1- BA  123 or 2. BA_123

I used Regex , it works if the string does not contain any white spaces or under score . 
Here is the  code used to split and increment by one:

```
string StrInputNumber="BA123" 
var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)"); 
var match = numAlpha.Match(StrInputNumber); 
var alpha = match.Groups["Alpha"].Value; 
int num = int.Parse(match.Groups["Numeric"].Value);
```

This works only for Alpha and numeric without any special characters

Please guide to solve this issue

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add those characters at the point where you expect them.

```
string[] StrInputNumber = { "BA123", "BA_123", "BA 123", "Foo 1"};
foreach (String item in StrInputNumber) {

    Console.Write(item + "\t==>\t");
    var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*[ _]?)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)");
    var match = numAlpha.Match(item);
    var alpha = match.Groups["Alpha"].Value;
    int num = int.Parse(match.Groups["Numeric"].Value) + 1;

    Console.WriteLine(alpha + num);
}
```

This would allow (optionally) one space or one `_` after the letters.

If you want to be more flexible, you can just add the characters in the class where the letters are.

```
var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z _]*)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)");
```

That would allow any amount of spaces and underscores anywhere before the digits in the string (e.g. "`Foo _ bar    ___  123`" would match).

**Unicode**

If you want to match all letters and not only the ASCII ones, try [Unicode code properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)

`\p{L}` would be any letter in any language

`\d` is a shorthand character class for digits

```
var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Alpha>[\p{L} _]*)(?<Numeric>\d*)");
```

**Further reading**

For some regex basics you can see

- my blog post [What absolutely every Programmer should know about regular expressions](http://blog.xisb.de/?p=4)
- tutorial on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) (a very good source on regular expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you ask but - if you have 1 whitespace or underscore:

```
var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)[ _]{1}(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)");
```

If you have many:

```
var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)[ _]*(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)");
```