# Add one to C# reference number

Tags: c#, numbers

My reference number is "DTS00001" it is a String variable in C# program
i want to increment this number by one and the result should be like "DTS00002"

here is the code i tried,

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    String str = reader["rfno"].ToString();
    String st = str.Substring(3, 5); 
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(st);                    
    number += 1;
    string myNewString = "DTS" + number;

    MessageBox.Show(myNewString);
```

The result doesn't contain the required leading zeros before the new number.

.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Sadly, we're not your personal code writing service.

Comment: You might start with, splitting the Alpha numeric and the numerics (using `string.Substring()`). use `int.TryParse()` to parse the numbers. Add 1 and reformat it

Comment: Parse the value into its component values, increment the numeric component value, re-combine them into a string.  Or, better yet, store the component values in a simple class which allows you to modify them and outputs the complete string from its `.ToString()` override.  That way you never need to parse anything.

Comment: String str = reader["rfno"].ToString();
                    String st = str.Substring(3, 5); 
                    int number = Convert.ToInt32(st);                    
                    number += 1;
                    string myNewString = "DTS" + number;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homework or not, here's one way to do it. It's **heavily** influensed by [stemas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10684731/4949005). It uses [`Regex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) to split the alphabetical from the numeric. And [`PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx) to maintain the right number of leading zeroes.

[Tim Schmelters answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40788263/4949005) is much more elegant, but this will work for other types of product-numbers as well, and is not limited to a specific number of leading zeros or a specific character set in the beginning. The downside with this solution is that it has to be [alphabetical][numerical].

```
private static string Increase(string productNo)
{
    // This is a regex to split it into to groups.
    var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*[ _]?)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)");
    // Match the input string for the regex.
    var match = numAlpha.Match(productNo);
    // Get the alphabetical part.
    var alpha = match.Groups["Alpha"].Value;
    // Get the numeric part.
    int num = int.Parse(match.Groups["Numeric"].Value);
    // Add +1
    num++;
    // Combine the alphabetical part with the increased number, but use PadLeft to maintain the padding (leading zeros).
    var newString = string.Format("{0}{1}", alpha, num.ToString().PadLeft(match.Groups["Numeric"].Value.Length, '0'));
    return newString;
}


Console.WriteLine(Increase("DTS00008"));
Console.WriteLine(Increase("DTS00010"));
Console.WriteLine(Increase("DTS00020"));
Console.WriteLine(Increase("DTS00099"));
Console.WriteLine(Increase("PRODUCT0000009"));
Console.WriteLine(Increase("PRODUCT0000001"));
```

Output:

```
DTS00009
DTS00011
DTS00021
DTS00100
PRODUCT0000010
PRODUCT0000002
```

Comment: $"{alpha}{num.ToString().PadLeft(match.Groups["Numeric"].Value.Length, '0')}"; in this code error occured saying ;expected

Comment: @Yasitha - Changed to old-school `string.Format` instead. _string interpolation_ may have some .NET version requirements.